# ant and command line arguments and absolute path

Tags: ant

All
I am passing a -D build.dir = ~/myhome/build to my ant script and when I echo build.dir it is coming out relative to where the build.xml is such as ./~/myhome/build.

I am using command line argument since I have to override a property defined in a properties file.

Thoughts on this?

Comment: another way of asking my question is: I have a build.dir property and when I delete dir ${build.dir} this is deleting the directory relative to my project. How do I force that to be the absolute value of build.dir property?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<project default="all" basedir="."> 
    <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties" />
    <target name="all">
        <echo message="${user.home}" />
        <propertyregex property="build.dir"
               input="${build.dir}"
               regexp="~"
               replace="${user.home}"
                override="true" />      
        <echo message="${build.dir}" />
    </target>
</project>
```

Comment: how does this answer my questions, I am not sure. I am trying to force a path to be absolute and not relative